# C# Double Clicking DataGridView vs Scroll Bar Issue Opening Duplicate Records

Tags: c#, wpf, datagridview, scroll

I am working on a WPF C# Application that includes a DataGridView with a Scroll Bar. I have written code so thatwhenever a row is selected it opens up the record. However, I noticed that when clicking on the scroll bar my application also registered this as a click event and was opening duplicate copies of the same record whenever the user double clicked on the scroll bar.

To prevent this I wrote code so that if the user opens the same record it does not open. The user has to click on another record, so they can open the same one after closing the record. This issue is a little annoying for the users, so I am trying to come up with a better solution.

At the moment I am using the MouseDoubleClicked Event Handler. Has anyone come across this issue before?

Answer (score 0):

Sounds like you need MouseDoubleClicked on the row, not the data grid itself.

```
<DataGrid>
    <DataGrid.RowStyle>
        <Style TargetType="DataGridRow" BasedOn="{StaticResource {x:Type DataGridRow}}">
            <EventSetter Event="MouseDoubleClick" Handler="DataGridRow_MouseDoubleClick" />
        </Style>
    </DataGrid.RowStyle>
</DataGrid>
```

Note that if you're using alternative theme(s), you'd have to change the "BasedOn" property to whatever DataGridRow style that is offered by the theme, otherwise you'd lose the row style which includes at least the background for row selection and may appear to be unselectable.